# How to apply numpy vectorize on a array of dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, vectorization

myfunc does some processes on a dataframe. I am trying to reduce computational time by vectorzing myfunc. Each dataframe are created by reading a very large text file(30 Gigs). I tried to create array of dataframes and then vectorize myfunc so that it can apply on array of dataframes, but the problem is that np.vectorize applies on each cell of a dataframe not on whole dataframe. Even though, I get some columns of dataframe as an array, np.vectorize applies myfunc on each cell inside an array not on whole array. I am not sure that is right way to solve this problem. Please share your thoughts. Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def myfunc(a):
    # Do some process on dataframe
    return a*2

vecfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc)

x = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]))
z = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]))


result = vecfunc([x,y,z])
print(result)
```

Comment: In case you missed out on reading the docs - `The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.`

Comment: @Divakar Question? But, do you normally see performance improvement with implementation of np.vectorize?

Comment: `np.vectorize` does not improve performance, and regardless, that is not an array of dataframes, but a `list`. The only realistic option you would have to make an array of dataframes would be to use `dtype=object`, but then you've lost all the efficiency gain s of `numpy.ndarray`s!

Comment: @ScottBoston Even if there is, shouldn't be any noticeable one. I haven't seen any solution that shows otherwise. Also, I haven't done enough research to show performance numbers on it.

Comment: Show us your defined function which you omit. Possibly that code can be optimized.

Comment: `vectorize` expects a function that takes one or more scalars.  It creates a function that broadcasts an equivalent number of arrays, feeding  the function with all 'broadcasted' elements.  There is a new signature parameter that allows more general functions, but it is even slower.  I've never seen it used with dataframes.